# Finding Emails for Japanese Professors

Tags: affiliation, japan

I'm an American Student Specializing in history, applying for a Fulbright program to Japan. Part of that Application process is securing a letter of affiliation from a Japanese university, Professor, or research institution. However, it's recommended you contact professors directly to pitch your project. There in lies the problem, as it is ridiculously hard to find contact information for most professors affiliated with Universities. I think this is simply a cultural difference, but it makes it very, very difficult to send out the mass amounts of emails I have to send in not a lot of time.

Does anyone know better ways of finding these emails or otherwise contacting these professors? I cannot call, since I have to have written proof of affiliation.

Thank you!

Comment: Sending mass emails is not going to work.  Customize.

Comment: It isn't "ridiculously hard": go to https://researchmap.jp/researchers, type some search criteria, and you'll get people profiles. You'll still have to go to their homepage to get some contact info, but still it'd help much to shortlist your contacts.